# How do I concatenate objects stored in an inheritance chain in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I am implementing a user interface.  Many objects expose various properties to the user interface.  They each have an object "ExposedProperties" that contains amongst other things a list of the exposed properties (and their types, how they should be displayed, how input should validated, etc.)  This ExposedProperties object is calculated once for each class.

I would like to get a concatenation of all of the exposed properties of an object.  One way to do this is for each object to pass its "ExposedProperties" up the inheritance chain in `__init__` and for each superclass to concatenate that with its own ExposedProperties.  A base class would set the concatenated ExposedProperties *on the object*.

Another way is to wait until the total exposed properties are requested from *an object*. Then, a base class method that scans *each class* in the `mro` for `exposed_properties` attributes concatenates them at that time.

What is the most Pythonic way to concatenate these objects stored in an inheritance chain in Python?

Comment: Other than using `super`?

Comment: Is the set of exposed properties for an object determined by its class, or can different instances of the same class expose different properties? Your description makes it sound as if the former is the case, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: Call the parent class's method and add the new elements to the returned list.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I think the problem is that super() is an object thing.  What I maybe want is some kind of "class finalizer" to visit the inheritance chain and compile the list once for the whole class.  Maybe a metaclass?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Yes, a metaclass would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Qq: if a superclass has a metaclass set on it, and a child class sets a metaclass, is that an error, or does the child metaclass override the superclass metaclass?

Comment: I don't actually know. I'd think that it would be overridden though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Thanks for your help.  FYI: "TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

Comment: I see. But that should be easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the exposed properties are class attributes, it makes sense to construct the desired list (of the exposed properties of the class together with those of its ancestors) at the time of class creation, for which you can use a metaclass.  (Edit:  I see the same suggestion was made in the comments.)

Here's an example of doing that:

```
class ExposedMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if not "exposed_properties" in attrs:
            cls.exposed_properties = []
        all_props = set(cls.exposed_properties)
        for base in bases:
            all_props.update(getattr(base, "all_exposed_properties", []))
        cls.all_exposed_properties = list(all_props)
        super(ExposedMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = ExposedMeta
    exposed_properties = ['A1', 'A2']

class B(A):
    exposed_properties = ['B']

class C(A):
    pass

class D(object):
    __metaclass__ = ExposedMeta
    exposed_properties = ['D']

class E(B, D):
    exposed_properties = ['E1', 'E2']

for cls in [A, B, C, D, E]:
    print "Class %s, exposed: %s, all exposed: %s" % (cls.__name__, cls.exposed_properties, cls.all_exposed_properties)
```